# Can I add some action when I push the Navigation back button in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm developing my first ios App.

I'm using Xcode 11.3 and Swift5

I'm not sure it is possible, can I add an action when I push the back button in NavigationLink?

[(In this picture, the back button is 'Bibles' button.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AJ4z.png)

```
NavigationLink(destination: VerseList(bible: self.bible, chapter: c.chapter)){
               ChapterRow(chapter: c.chapter)
            }.navigationBarTitle("Chapters")
```

This is my code. and I want to add 'action'..

Is there any better way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be more likely be like this.

```
NavigationLink(destination:VerseList(bible: self.bible, chapter: c.chapter)
                   .onDisappear {
                       // put action here
                   }
              ){ChapterRow(chapter: c.chapter)}
.navigationBarTitle("Chapters")
```